# C# Windows Form start up always minimized

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed a C# Windows Form.
At first, the Windows Form works fine.
However, one day the Windows Form starts up always minimized and I have no idea.
I checked the `WindowState` is `Normal` not `Minimized`.
How Can I fix it, Thanks!

### **Edit:**

I comment each code block to narrow the scope to locate the problem point.
And I found that I used a [Drive Detector](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program) in my MainForm.
When that instance was created, the call Window form must be passed as a parameter to the constructor.
Otherwise, the `Drive Detector` will create a hidden form. However, the MainForm will be minimized.

The below code will NOT create a hidden form.

```
driveDetector = new DriveDetector(this);
```

The below code will create a hidden form, it will interfere the call Windows Form.

```
driveDetector = new DriveDetector();
```

Comment: Since when is this the case? If you use a subversioning system, you can take a look on what changed between the two commits...

Comment: @CommuSoft That's a good idea. Unfortunately, I haven't use any Version Control System....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add this code in form load event and test

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try to add it from the code level to say the windows state as follows.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use `WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized` if you wish to open your windows in full screen by default. You can do this programmatically in `Form load` event.

There are other various options available too from which you can control on How to open your windows form.

Comment: I change the `WindowState` to `Maximized`, but it is minimized too. It maximizes at the background.

Comment: If I set the `TopMost` true, the problem is solved. But I don't want the Form always on the top...

Comment: The `IsMdiContainer` property of the Form is false.

Comment: do you have any other forms in application? or this is the only one?

Comment: I have many forms in the application, and the problem occurs on the main form.

Answer (score 2):

1.Check whether you have set the size of form to smaller one.

2.Try re-build your solution.

3.Add Form Load Event from your Events Properties of Form and add following code to it

> this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it in form activated event

```
    bool bIsLoaded = false;
    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!bIsLoaded)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            bIsLoaded = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I comment each code block to narrow the scope to locate the problem point.
And I found that I used a [Drive Detector](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program) in my MainForm.
When that instance was created, the call Window form must be passed as a parameter to the constructor.
Otherwise, the `Drive Detector` will create a hidden form. However, the MainForm will be minimized.

The below code will NOT create a hidden form.

```
driveDetector = new DriveDetector(this);
```

The below code will create a hidden form, it will interfere the call Windows Form.

```
driveDetector = new DriveDetector();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Topmost = true;
```

In your Form_Load event